# Can I Track Online Customer History and Cart?

Tags: customer, google-analytics

I've searched and haven't found exactly what I'm looking for.  Back when I used osCommerce, I had something similar to this coded, but that was a much more simple system to hack away at.

I'd like to pull up a real-time report (similar to Google Analytics Real-Time) that tells me how many active [human] visitors are shopping at my store at any given time.  I'd then like the ability to click on one to view their history (past visit dates/lengths, current visit trail and current items in cart).  In fact, if there is a way to do this with GA, that would be fine with me!

**Why?**  Because I want to see where in the funnel people are getting bogged down in real time and see instant response to newly launched promotions.   Also, I would like the ability to display a cart ID to a customer during checkout with our phone number so they can finish the checkout verbally in case they either don't like on-line ordering or are having a problem.  That would expedite the process of phone reps looking up products for a customer.

Has anybody had experience with an extension or service similar to this for Magento?

Answer (score 2):

Try this extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-analytics-by-fooman.html

It will help you funnel your checkout.

If your customer tells the account they are using; sales reps can see the cart in the account overview and finish from there...

Comment: I've seen that extension before and wasn't aware it would do what I'm asking.   I just checked the link and don't see information relevant to this question either.   How does it make cart contents, past pages, etc viewable in real time?  I thought that extension only sent more granular information to GA (like AJAX loads).